# c# move images from datagridview to dataset

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, datagridview

In my Program I have the option to upload five images. I've been storing them in a table with a datagridview

```
  private void metroButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (counter <= 9)
        {
            dgdImages.Rows[0].Cells[counter].Value = pictureBox1.Image;
            dgdImages.Rows[0].Cells[oddcounter].Value = txtImgName.Text;
            counter++;
            counter++;
            oddcounter++;
            oddcounter++;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("System currently only supports five images per Contaimination area");
        }
    }
```

After holding them in the datagridview, I want to move them to a database in my dataset when the user has finished the form

```
if (i < conTotal)
        {
            DataRow anyRow;

            anyRow = epasDataSet.ContaminationAreas.NewRow();
            anyRow[0] =  txtContaminationAreaName.Text;
            anyRow[1] = txtConArea.Text;
            anyRow[2] = dgdImages.Rows[0].Cells[1];
            anyRow[3] = dgdImages.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value;
 epasDataSet.ContaminationAreas.Rows.Add(anyRow);
            dataGridView1.Refresh();
        }
```

However when I run I get the following error message

```
 Type of value has a mismatch with column typeCouldn't store <System.Drawing.Bitmap> in Photo 1 Column.  Expected type is Byte[].
```

I don't know how to convert the image, or is there a better way of storing the images until its synced with the database?